# golang - No such file or directory even when file exists

Tags: go

I have a container running go1.18. But I am not able to execute a go binary file on it.
The error I get is `No such file or directory` even though the file exists on the system.

```
root@b5840a7e3deb:/goapp# go get bitbucket.xvz.com/xxx_gosdk/genlog
go: downloading bitbucket.xvz.com/xxx_gosdk/genlog v0.0.0-20180720150703-5438fece8851
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: downloading github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1


    root@b5840a7e3deb:/goapp# go generate  ./applogs/...
    applogs/loggen.go:2: running "genlog": exec: "genlog": executable file not found in $PATH
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# echo $PATH
    /go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# find . -name genlog
    ./target/bin/genlog
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# export PATH=/goapp/target/bin:$PATH
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# go generate  ./applogs/...
    applogs/loggen.go:2: running "genlog": exec: "genlog": executable file not found in $PATH
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# ./target/bin/genlog
    bash: ./target/bin/genlog: No such file or directory
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# ls -ltr ./target/bin/genlog
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5785472 Jul 15 11:55 ./target/bin/genlog
    root@b5840a7e3deb:/goapp# cd target/bin/
    root@b5840a7e3deb:/goapp/target/bin# ./genlog
    bash: ./genlog: No such file or directory
    root@f27b28c39c4b:/goapp# go version
    go version go1.18.3 linux/amd64


Not sure what could be the reason of this? 

Both file and linux are 64-bit.

    root@b5840a7e3deb:/goapp/target/bin# file genlog
    genlog: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, Go BuildID=5_YjQVva2uu05mM9OtMl/4DKTh04b6KayyO-oCXMx/S56k25kGovKc_B70LVqf/UnqDZDQQtMFSIfz-py0j, not stripped
    root@b5840a7e3deb:/goapp/target/bin# uname -a
    Linux b5840a7e3deb 5.4.17-2136.308.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Mon Jun 13 20:40:51 PDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Update: I figured that I was missing a program interpreter which I installed using apt-get. But `ldd` is still complaining that the interpreter is missing.

    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp/target/bin# ldd genlog
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedee39000)
        libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp/target/bin# readelf -a genlog | grep interpreter
          [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1]
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp# ls /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
    ls: cannot access '/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1': No such file or directory
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp# apt-get install musl
    ...
    Unpacking musl:amd64 (1.1.24-1) ...
    Setting up musl:amd64 (1.1.24-1) ...
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp# cd target/bin/
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp/target/bin# ls -ltr /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Oct 13  2019 /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 -> x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp/target/bin# ./genlog 
    genlog: error while reading file '': open : no such file or directory
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp/target/bin# ldd genlog
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedee39000)
        libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
    root@f718aa896bd6:/goapp/target/bin# readelf -a genlog | grep interpreter
          [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1]
```

Comment: I think you have to install 'genlog' in order to resolve this issue, it would be better if you add more detailed description of what you are doing. what tools you are using with go generate. @codingenious

Comment: The file is not executable with `./genlog` too.

Comment: is genlog installed on your container ? I mean is the genlog itself accessible via $PATH and also can you post your go generate call here?

Comment: your `$PATH` is `/goapp/target/bin/genlog`, it should have been `/goapp/target/bin`

Comment: ah. Right. After correcting that, still getting `genlog: error while reading file '': open : no such file or directory` when running `genlog`.

Comment: @Aliy We can ignore `go generate` as, the binary itself is not executing using ./genlog. It is a go binary which I got using `go get` command as shown above.

Comment: `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1` is a symbolic link to `x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so`, so `/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so` must exist and be loadable; if it does not, the program will not be executable. If it *does* exist, that doesn't mean the program will be executable or will work: it's a *necessary* condition, not a *sufficient* one; there may be more conditions.